# Menu bar icon disappears after window resize

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift4

I created the default Cocoa macOS project in Xcode and modified AppDelegate so that it adds a menu bar icon and makes the application window fullscreen. What happens instead is that the window appears normally and the menu bar icon (which should be a T) flashes very quickly in the macOS status bar and disappears. If I comment out the code in applicationDidFinishLaunching, the menu bar icon works. If I remove awakeFromNib and don't create a status item, the application becomes fullscreen. If I try to do both at the same time, it won't work, and I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong. This is the main part of my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
var item = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

override func awakeFromNib() {
    let menu = NSMenu(title: "W")
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(AppDelegate.quit), keyEquivalent: ""))

    item.title = "T"
    item.menu = menu
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first!
    window.setFrame(NSScreen.main!.frame, display: true)
}
```

Comment: "the menu bar icon (which should be a T) flashes very quickly in the macOS status bar and disappears"  I don't see the icon you are talking about anywhere.

Comment: Where is your NSMenu IBOutlet object?

Comment: I don't need one because I make a new NSMenu in awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out

```
let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first!
```

doesn't return the application window, but it seems to return the menu icon. I changed this to

```
let window = NSApplication.shared.windows[1]
```

and it worked.